# Safe transaction keeps failing because the nonce have been used

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I have a 2 of 2 multisig safe account where my users sign and I also sign with my own dedicated private key which is also responsible for transaction execution. I need the user's signature for transactions I plan to execute in the future like token allowance, smart contract transactions. So right now they sign those transactions and I store those signatures in the database. I plan to only make a blockchain transaction like safe deployment and these transactions signed by my users after they have been verify by my platform. The issue is that for a new safe account that have not performed any blockchain transaction the nonce is 0. So when the first transaction succeeds the nonce changes to 1 thereby making other transaction to fails because they are using old nonce. Please any idea on how I can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign a transaction and save it to execute later, as long as it complies with how Safe [handles signed transactions](https://docs.safe.global/safe-smart-account/signatures/eip-1271). You will need to keep track and increment the nonce each time *before signing* each transaction, so that each one have a different nonce and be broadcast to the network.

Hope it helps, Louis